# Facebook SDK iOS - Authorise In-App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I have found that in the Facebook.m class I can do this:

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

I changed each of these from YES to NO as I don't want to user to leave my application to authorise my application.

However now having done that I get no in-app prompt of any kind to authorise, so how can I authorise myself now inside my application without the user going to either Safari or the Facebook app to authorise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see what your problem is.

in my opinion get the latest 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk
and then override

```
[device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)] && [device isMultitaskingSupported]
```

in facebook.m to always return false line 160

Comment: For the current version (3.5.1) you should change -(BOOL)isMultitaskingSupported on FBSession.m (line 1149)

Answer (score 0):

Because Facebook (and Twitter) use oAuth, you need to use a webpage to run the authorization. However, using a webpage to do authorization is *not* the same as leaving your app to do authorization.

I believe the way that Facebook authorization in many apps is done with a UIWebView in the app. You can have a look at [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/) and how they've implemented several "in app" authorizations for various services.