# Custom in-app login and authorisation with Facebook and iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I am just starting out with the Facebook SDK for iOS. Where should I start if I want to firstly:

Have a custom login screen in-app, so the user enters their email and password inside my app to login.

Secondly:

Authorise the application in-app without leaving to authorise through Safari or The official Facebook app?

An example is Facely HD for the iPhone, as when you first use it you enter your login details and then are asked to authorised all without leaving the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of your two earlier posts [Facebook SDK iOS - Authorise In-App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157597/facebook-sdk-ios-authorise-in-app) **and** [Facebook iOS authorize and post without dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144457/facebook-ios-authorise-and-post-without-dialog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In facebook.m in the Facebook iOS SDK, you can call `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO]` and this will popup the standard UIWebView. That should cover both options as first the Facebook login screen will appear and then after that the prompt to authorize your application will appear.

Comment: Thats interesting, as I have downloaded the latest version of the SDK and after making those changes already I found it stops leaving my app, but no such webview or dialog appears. Could there be a reason for this?

Comment: It should work, I changed it in their demo application and it worked fine.  Try it on their demo app.

Comment: Just tried in the DemoApp and it worked. I can't see how my code is any different however. Are there specific methods and delegates I need to get this to work or something similar?

Comment: Not 100% sure - but I would start comparing line by line the differences. The facebook demo app is pretty basic so it shouldn't be too hard.  Did you make sure to set your appID in code?

Comment: Not sure what it may have been , possibly including dialogDidComplete method, it may have been required and just did my best to follow the code structure of the demo app it it works now! Thanks for all the help, let me in the right direction.